# How can we train a deep learning model for input of any length?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have created a deep learning model, using keras. I am training the model on comments of different lengths. I pre-processed the input data, and padded it to equal length. While predicting, if I give an input, with length larger then that of my training inputs, model fails. What should I do? Kindly share some examples as well that will be really helpful.

```
latent_dim = 1024
inpt = Input(shape=(max_len,))  ### max_len is the final length
emb_layer = Embedding(vocabulary_size, 100, weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable = False)(inpt)
bdlstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(64, return_sequences = True))(emb_layer)
dns2 = Dense(no_labels, activation='softmax')(bdlstm1)
model = Model(inpt, dns2)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you'll find a satisfying answer here:

https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/how-can-neural-networks-deal-with-varying-input-sizes

The best (and only simple) way is to use RNN.

Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically the limitation is given by the fully-connected layer/s at the end of the deep net, having all its units the need of be feeded.

Due to this limitation, we must fix the length normally *a priori* (max number of words in NLP). As I've seen in your code, you're using a 100-size embedding layer, so for every sentence that doesn't reach the minimum size you have to add 100 zeros for every missing word.

For longer sentences (as is the case you are commenting on) you can do the following, but you should know that you will lose information since words that exceed will not be taken into account for the prediction.

```
if max_len < len(sentence.split()):
    # add zero padding until reach max_len
else:
    inputSentence = " ".join(sentence.split()[:max_len]) # no. words = max_len
```

Answer (score 0):

you used LSTM whis is a kind of RNN and it requires max time steps so you must limit upper bound of text.

if new input longer than max_len

- clip it to a max_len
- or use sliding window  and make prediction for each of them and use average of them